# cakephp combining two sql statements

Tags: sql, cakephp, find

hi all  I have two sql statements in my function, I want to take the result of the $accounts and use that as the where clause in my second statement. I am trying to get the account_id from the accounts_users table so I can get the relevant templates to that account.

the two finds are called $templates and $accounts, I want the result of the first query to be used for what template.account_id= 'answer' is.

```
SELECT `AccountsUser`.`id`, `AccountsUser`.`account_id` FROM `pra`.`accounts_users` AS `AccountsUser` WHERE `id` = 14 LIMIT 1

SELECT `Template`.`id`, `Template`.`name`, `Template`.`description`, `Template`.`account_id` FROM `pra`.`templates` AS `Template` WHERE `Template`.`account_id` = ''
```

this is the code in my controller

```
$this->Template->unbindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Account')));
        $templates = $this->Auth->user('name');
        $accounts=$this->User->AccountsUser->find('first', array('fields'=>array('id','account_id'),'conditions' =>     array('id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
        $this->set('Templates', $this->Template->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Template.account_id' => $accounts))));
        $this->set('templates', $templates);
        $this->set('accounts'. $accounts);
```

view 'view'

```
<div class = "conlinks">        

<table width="100%" border="1">

            <table width="100%" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Template Name</th>
                    <th>Template Description</th>

                </tr>

                <?php foreach($templates as $template): ?>
                    <tr> 
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $template['Template']['name']; ?></td>
                        <td align='center'><?php echo $template['Template']['description']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </table>

</div>              
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following:

```
    $this->Template->unbindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Account')));
    $templates = $this->Auth->user('name');
    $accounts=$this->User->AccountsUser->find('list', array('fields'=>array('id', 'account_id'),'conditions' =>  array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));       
    $this->set('Templates', $this->Template->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Template.account_id' => $accounts['AccountsUser']))));
    $this->set('templates', $templates);
    $this->set('accounts'. $accounts);
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: nameSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: no, this user has an account_id of 10, he also has created templates as well

Comment: array with nothing in it was printed at the top

Comment: i think the issue is - the template table has account_id but its storing the id of the accounts_users table(accounts_users.id), not the accounts_users.account_id.

Comment: just tried your updated code Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AccountsUser] => Array
                (
                    [account_id] => 10
                )

        )

)

Comment: Array
(
    [3] => 10
)

that is correct, its pulling the account_id now

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined index: AccountsUser [APP\Controller\TemplatesController.php, line 70]

Comment: yeah its prints out the array still. exactly the same, it doesnt like AccountsUser though in the last array